# HTML vertical bar of two different colors

Tags: html

I want to make in HTML some statistic bar charts, to represent in the same bar two different values using two different colours, for example: from an exam of 10 questions, 6 question were correctly answered and 4 wrong. In the bar should appear the 60% green and the other 40% red.

I have been thinking in display the red one first, and the green one over it, so it covers the the lower part, something like this:

Style

```
.bar1{
    width:40px;
    background-color:#A55541;
    position:left;
}
.bar2{
    width:40px;
    background-color:#CA804F;
    position:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="height:<?=$max ?>px; margin-top:10px;" class="bar1"</div>
<div style="height:<?=$max-($mistakes*$scale) ?>px; margin-top:10px;" class="bar2"</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve it?? I have been looking for a similar question on here but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You've got missing `>` signs. And aren't `mistakes` and `scale` supposed to start with `$`?

Comment: You are right about the $, because in my script I'm using differnt names and when I post this I just wrote a simple example. Thank you!! but I don't know where I'm missing  ">" you mean before style?? because I think there is not necessary

Comment: You're missing it after class="bar1" and bar2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$max = 300;
$mistakes = 100;
$scale = 1;
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:<?=$max ?>px;" class="bar1"></div>
<div style="height:<?=$max-(mistakes*scale) ?>px;" class="bar2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bar1{
    width:40px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
}
.bar2{
    width:40px;
    background-color:green;
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BDNXS/

Comment: This works just perfect when I want to draw only 1 bar, but I tried to make the script a little bit complex drawing several of this bar bars together, but they are drawn one over another. I created a new question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279715/html-problems-drawing-bar-charts I tried to group the bars in pairs with a <div class="group"> but it doesn't work, they still appear on over another. What would you recommend me to do??

Answer (score 1):

To make this code work properly, Make another class like:

```
.container {
       width : 40px;
       height: 100px;
       position: relative
 }
```

And make bar1 position relative and bar2 position absolute, bottom: 0px and z-index: 100. Now add your two divs inside the container class and set bar2 'top' instead of height in php.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do what you said, but it's not working how I expected. I'm completly new with HTML and CSS and probably I'm just making silly mistakes, here is a complementary question I made about this tiopic, with the ideas I got from your answer and Tiago's answer. Thank you very much for your help!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279715/html-problems-drawing-bar-charts

Answer (score 0):

Does this match what you're looking for?

```
<?php
$max = 100;
$mistakes = 40;
$scale = 1;
?>
<html>
<style>
.bar1{
    width:40px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
        z-index:1;
        position: absolute;
}
.bar2{
    width:40px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    z-index:2;
        position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div style="height:<?php echo $max ?>px;" class="bar1"></div>
<div style="height:<?php echo $max -($mistakes*$scale) ?>px;" class="bar2"></div>
</html>
```

I added an echo and got rid of the margin-top because it messes up the layout I think you're going for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it doesn't work. I tested it and it appears only a red bar on the right top corner of the screen.

Comment: that only worked because of the missing > after class="bar1" and class="bar2"